# iOS on iPad Disabling Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, safari, web-audio-api

***Please note: This issue was fixed Nov 2016 in iOS 10.1.1. Thank you Apple!***

I am unable to play any audio through Web Audio API on iPad. This is using the latest version of iOS (since 9.3.2 - currently 10.1).

**Test Case**

Here is [a bare-bones test](https://www.sharphosting.uk/ipad_test.html) I have set up (code below). None of the tests work on iPad for me. No problems on iPhone or other compatible browsers. There is [another test page here](http://www.williammalone.com/posts/ios-9-web-audio-api-safari-mobile-issue/) (from William Malone). None of those sounds play on three iPads tried. Finally [this game](http://pbskids.org/naturecat/game.html?racing-rapids) uses Web Audio API (thanks Derek) and is also muted.

If you are reading this on iPad, please try that [bare-bones test](https://www.sharphosting.uk/ipad_test.html) and report in the comments (or [contact me privately](https://www.sharphosting.uk/contact)) if load, followed by play, works and plays sound. Please include iOS version number (Settings -> General -> About -> Version).

Any insights or feedback would be much appreciated!

Here is the test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Web Audio API - iPad Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="./jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        section { padding:10px; margin:0 0 10px; background:DarkSeaGreen }
        a { cursor:pointer; display:block; background: DarkSeaGreen; padding:10px; margin:0 0 3px }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var app = {};
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Do we have Web Audio API?
            try {
                window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
                audioContext = new AudioContext();
            } catch (e) {
                alert('Web Audio API is not supported in this browser');
            }
            $('#loadClick').on('click',function(){load('./ipad_test.mp3')});
            $('#playTouchEnd').on('touchend',play);
            $('#playTouchStart').on('touchstart',play);
            $('#playClick').on('click',play);
            $('#unlockTouchEnd').on('touchend',unlock);
            $('#unlockTouchStart').on('touchstart',unlock);
            $('#unlockClick').on('click',unlock);
        });
        function unlock() {
            // play empty buffer to unmute audio
            var buffer = audioContext.createBuffer(1, 1, 22050);
            var source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
            source.audioContext = buffer;
            source.connect(audioContext.destination);
            source.start(0);
            $('#messages').append('<p>Unlocked.</p>');
        }
        function load(file) {
            if(app.loaded) {
                $('#messages').append('<p>Already loaded.</p>');
                return;
            }
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open ('GET', file, true);
            request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
            request.onload = function () {
                audioContext.decodeAudioData(
                        request.response,
                        function (buffer) {
                            app.buffer = buffer;
                            $('#messages').append('<p>Loaded.</p>');
                            app.loaded = 1;
                        },
                        function(){alert('Load error.');}
                )
            };
            request.send();
        }
        function play() {
            if(!app.loaded) {
                $('#messages').append('<p>Please load before playing.</p>');
                return;
            }
            var sourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
            sourceNode.buffer = app.buffer;
            sourceNode.connect (audioContext.destination);
            sourceNode.start(0);
            $('#messages').append('<p>Playing.</p>');
        }
    </script>
    <h1>Web Audio API Test</h1>
    <p>Unlock should not be needed at all, but offers an alternative way to try and get the audio going. Load and then play should be all any compatible device needs. Refresh to start again.</p>
    <a id="unlockTouchEnd">Unlock (touchend)</a>
    <a id="unlockTouchStart">Unlock (touchstart)</a>
    <a id="unlockClick">Unlock (click)</a>
    <a id="loadClick" style="background:#c0c0c0">Load (click)</a>
    <a id="playTouchEnd">Play Audio (touchend)</a>
    <a id="playTouchStart">Play Audio (touchstart)</a>
    <a id="playClick">Play Audio (click)</a>
    <section id="messages"></section>
</body>
</html>
```

**Background**

The [Apple documentation makes it clear](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds.html) that audio must be initiated from a user action for Web Audio API to work. They state:

> Note: On iOS, the Web Audio API requires sounds to be triggered from an explicit user action, such as a tap. Calling noteOn() from an onload event will not play sound.

There are a number of threads online about problems with this, the latest being autumn 2015 with iOS 9.0 to 9.2:

- [Thread from HTML 5 Game Devs](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/17326-ios-9-webaudio-issues/) (autumn 2015 problems)
- [William Malone](http://www.williammalone.com/posts/ios-9-web-audio-api-safari-mobile-issue/) (autumn 2015 problems)
- [Paul Bakaus](https://paulbakaus.com/tutorials/html5/web-audio-on-ios/) (unlocking techniques)
- [Adrian Holovaty](http://www.holovaty.com/writing/ios9-web-audio/) (autumn 2015 problems)

They suggest firing audio from a touchstart event to unlock iOS audio (or touchend while there were issues at that time). I have tried all of the suggested techniques and can't get touchstart, touchend or click to work. The audio is always muted on iPad.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but have you checked your mute switch?

This has happened to me a number of times with Web Audio stuff on iOS devices. I forget that I had my phone set to vibrate, and the browser won't play any sounds.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, first thing I tried. I usually play some audio from something else on the device to check it.

Comment: A wild guess: Chrome on Win Desktop has the ability to 'Mute tab' (access by right-clicking). Is this happening by default on your browser, and perhaps set from Preferences?

Comment: Thanks for this. No, it's not that. This has been tested on 3 iPads, which all play other audio, including other audio from websites, such as YouTube, fine. And there is no such setting on iPad.

Comment: Crossing my fingers that iOS 10 will fix this in the fall! apple.com/ios/ios10-preview And perhaps even an interim update to fix it for the nine series? I have tried posting twice about this on the Apple dev forum for Safari iOS web apps but the post is not being accepted by the moderators.

Comment: We're getting this same behavior reported from an iPhone 6s, but our iPad Mini works fine (9.3.2). Have you tried different sample or bit rates on your test mp3 to see if that makes a difference? Or the content-type? We don't have a test device in-house that's showing this behavior, but if I created a few variations of your test page, could you check them out on one of your iPads?

Comment: Hi Derek. Great to hear from you! Certainly, I'd be happy to do that on the two devices I have here that exhibit the behaviour. I haven't tried playing with bit rates or content-type in any detail.

Comment: Hi Nigel, here is a test page with a couple variations: http://gopherwoodstudios.com/wa/ If you know of a website where the web audio api /does/ work for mp3's on your devices, let me know - I'm curious to find whether there is a particular header or format that works for playback on these iOS devices. I've tried all of these on my iPad Mini and they work fine.

Comment: This is great to have Derek. Unfortunately only to eliminate it, as none of the tests work on the iPad Air 2 here with 9.3.2 installed. The audio is always muted. Works fine on an iPhone 6. Do you have any other ideas? I am wondering about loading the audio from <audio> tags instead of AJAX to see if that helps.

Comment: Oddly enough, the iPhone 6s issue I mentioned earlier turned out to be the phone being set on "vibrate". This setting allows videos and such to play, but apparently mutes the audio api so that web pages using it are muted. Here's a game that I know uses the web audio api - if it works on your devices, I'll pull all of its header and format info and create a simpler test: http://pbskids.org/naturecat/game.html?racing-rapids

Comment: Ah, interesting. I did wonder at that, as only seen this issue on iPad. That game is muted on this iPad. All other audio functioning fine before and after trying it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm running out of ideas. I added one more test using aac instead of mp3 if you want to test it out: http://gopherwoodstudios.com/wa/aac/test.htm If all of these various formats aren't working, my initial hunch about it being an odd file-type issue is quite likely incorrect and something else is going on. :-)

Comment: Thanks Derek. That one won't play either. I appreciate your efforts. Good to eliminate that possibility thoroughly. iOS 10 will hopefully fix it! That is looking like the best hope and give up on 9 unfortunately. Although one never knows! A fix could come. I will be trying loading from <audio> elements soon.

Comment: iOS 9.3.3 just out but failed to fix this issue.

Comment: Ditto for iOS 9.3.4.

Comment: This is fixed in the latest 10.1.1. They released an updated build of 10.1.1 and the previous one didn't fix it. I updated again today and everything now works. Yay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple fixed this issue in iOS 10.1.1 November 2016. Thank you Apple!